# Can not sync or build project because of "Gradle Doctor Prescriptions | JAVA_HOME is not set" and "Failed to notify project evaluation listener"

Tags: gradle

I can not sync or build Android project because of two errors:

1. Firstly, I got:

```
> =============================== Gradle Doctor Prescriptions ============================================
  | JAVA_HOME is not set.                                                                                |
  | Please set JAVA_HOME so that switching between Android Studio and the terminal does not trigger a fu |
  | ll rebuild.                                                                                          |
  | To set JAVA_HOME: (using bash)                                                                       |
  | echo "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile                                 |
  | or `~/.zshrc` if using zsh.                                                                          |
  ========================================================================================================
```

2. Then after **Clean Project**

```
/Library/Internet
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Library/Internet
    at com.osacky.doctor.JavaHomeCheck.isGradleUsingJavaHome(JavaHomeCheck.kt:68)
    at com.osacky.doctor.JavaHomeCheck.onStart(JavaHomeCheck.kt:41)
    at com.osacky.doctor.DoctorPlugin$apply$1.execute(DoctorPlugin.kt:61)
    at com.osacky.doctor.DoctorPlugin$apply$1.execute(DoctorPlugin.kt:29)
```

I'm pretty sure that **JAVA_HOME is set correctly** and the **Gradle version is compatible with the plugin** version as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle).
I cleaned the project, made "invalidate and restart", even deleted and added the project.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution: to get rid of the error I need to disable one of the plugins in the `build.gradle.kts` (Project level)

I solved it by removal of `id("com.osacky.doctor") version "0.7.0"` from `plugins`

Comment: Did you find a solution to fix it? I'm in the same situation and I'm pretty sure that JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

Comment: @MajidKhosravi sorry, mate, I didn't